# jquery mobile selected option not updating on 'refresh'

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-mobile, refresh

Using jQueryMobile, when I change the contents of a select widget and then call 'refresh' on it, the text of the selected option is not changed.  Here's the scenario...

The 'select' widget exists in the page div already.  When the user goes to that screen, the options are dynamically created based on the button they selected to go to that page.  This option list is built and added as per

```
$('#searchReasonList').append(optionList)
```

The first time into the new page all works well.  When they navigate away and come back in, I do

```
$('#searchReasonList').empty()
```

Then I build the correct option list and do the same append and call:

```
$('#searchReasonList').selectmenu('refresh',true)
```

The native select is indeed refreshed, and I am able to choose from the options.  However, the selected option doesn't show up.  Only the placeholder is seen.

To show the enhanced markup:

```
<div class="ui-select">
  <div class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" data-theme="c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">Select Reason</span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow"></span>
    </span>

    <select id="searchReasonList" name="searchReasonList" data-placeholder="true">
      <option value="">Select Reason</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's that span tag with `class='ui-btn-text'` that is not being updated with the selected option's label.  It just stays "Search Reason", which is the label of my placeholder.

Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: What version of jQuery Mobile are you using?

Comment: 1.0.1, the latest stable version at this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using jQuery 1.0.1 (latest stable version at this time) you can use `.selectmenu('refresh')` to refresh a select-widget.

```
$('select').empty().append('<option value="foo">Bar</option>').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Thzt/

When you use `$('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);` (notice the `, true`), you are forcing the widget to not only be refreshed, but rebuilt, which will always show the placeholder text. *Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/selects/methods.html*

Comment: your jsfiddle page certainly works.  but regardless if i include that 2nd 'true' arg or not, my selected option just doesn't show.  the only difference i can see is that i'm coming into the page again.  the onclick handler for my button creates the option list, empties the select, appends the option list to the select, then calls $.mobile.changePage, then calls refresh on the selectmenu.  nothing really complex happening.  that span just doesn't get updated in my case.

Comment: @dlgrasse Do you have a link to the site in question?

Comment: no - sorry.  but you prompt me to create a simple version of my scenario and verify nothing else i have is corrupting the behavior.

Comment: @dlgrasse Can you post all of the event binding and the select refresh code?

Comment: let me trim it down to the essentials and i will.

Comment: taking out other code did expose the problem.  i had a 'change' event handler on the select which i was un-binding when you navigated away.  but my unbind call didn't specify my event-handler function, so _all_ change handlers were being detached.  hence jQueryMobile's handler wasn't being called to change that span.

Comment: thanks for your assistance.  seeing the jsFiddle screen work forced me to inspect my code more closely.

Comment: @dlgrasse You can add a namespace to event bindings so you can trigger or unbind only the event handler you want to: `$element.bind('click.my-namespace')` -- `$element.trigger('click.my-namespace')` -- `$element.unbind('click.my-namespace')`. This way you don't mess with anybody else's bindings.

Comment: i didn't know that. thanks for the tip. thinking through my situation, i'm still surprised their event handler worked the first time. this implies that they don't bind until the page-div that holds the widget to be enhanced is shown; and that the .selectmenu('refresh',true) call doesn't completely rebuild the enhanced widget, at least in terms of rebinding events. i'll go ahead and mark this answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I had a similar problem with multiselect menus. Before adding true, which forces the menu to be rebuilt, multiselect boxes would always clear, but the checkmark would still persist. After adding true, as mentioned above, multiselect checkmarks were removed. Thanks a lot @Jasper.