# select list value not remains constant after making call to another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html.dropdownlistfor

see i have one form which contains select drop downlist and 2 textbox .In one textbox click option i am going to one page which contains contact list. i am appending the value from that page and again i am returning back to my old page.so after this whatever the value i changed in dropdown select list  before its get changed to default value as 1.its not remain same as before.below is my code.
 this is my html form.

```
   <body onload="main();">
        <select id="privacy" onchange="getPri(this)">
                    <option value="1" >1</option>
                    <option value="2" >2</option>
                  </select>
                  <input type="text" value="choose contacts" id="to" onClick="window.location='contact.html';">
                  </input>
```

and this is my js

function getPri(sel)
    {
    var value = sel.value;

```
if(value=="2")
{ 

$("#to").show();
}
else
{
 $("#to").hide();

}}
```

where as in contact.html,i am havving contact list, i am appending the one of the contact from that and appending it to the same textbox which is havving id to.

```
 function main()
              {
    var contact = "";
              if ( sessionStorage.getItem("contact") ) {
              contact = sessionStorage.getItem("contact");

              $("#to").val(postneedcontact);
}
```

Now the problem is as suppose i m selected value 2 then contact textbox will show.now after clicking on this i am able to append this value and everything is working correctly.the problem is that the value which i get selected now its changed to again 1.which i want it to set it what it was previously selected by me as 2 because if 1 is selected then contact textbox will hide as shown in the code.so any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming contact is new page, why dont you try to save select box selection value into some storage ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can do this using webstorage like localstorage, i did this using localstorage. When user select any option from dropdown the index is saved in localstorage an in page load retrieved that index and assigned to dropdown.

Please note that this will not run on online editor it needs browser because of localstorage of browser. Please run this in your browser.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
    var iVal;
    window.onload=function(){
        iVal=document.getElementById("privacy");
        iVal.selectedIndex=localStorage.getItem("PrivacyVal");
    };
        function getPri(){
            localStorage.setItem("PrivacyVal", iVal.selectedIndex);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <select id="privacy" onchange="getPri()">
            <option  >1</option>
            <option  >2</option>
            <option  >3</option>
            <option  >4</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may i know which browser version are you using?

Comment: Please use updated version of browser and your browser must support HTML5. I have updated above code with program that is running in my browser perfectly.

Comment: ,the problem is after selecting list suppose i m selected 2 in option then i am going to another page.and after returning back now this select value again defaults to  1 which is error for me because if i select 1 then that textbox will hide and i dont need to go to anypage.

Comment: The drop down is assigned after loading a page, so whatever value we have assigned is not reflected so refresh the select using .selectmenu('refresh')   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709182/jquery-mobile-selected-option-not-updating-on-refresh